# discord.py block advertisment isnt working

Tags: python

I have recently started learning discord.py, and I am trying to remove certain links when they get posted in a channel. Please see my below code.

```
@Bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  if "discord.gg" in message.content.lower():
    await message.delete()
    await message.channel.send("Luften Reklam Yapmaurn!")
  await Bot.process_commands(message)
```

Comment: Can you copy and paste your code into your question rather than linking to a picture of it?

Comment: This has been edited to be clearer and can be reopened

Answer (score 0):

Here I have made a very basic link or word filter, it will look through the whole message for anything containing the specific key words specified below;

Depending if you also want to allow bots to send links, just remove the if `message.author.bot:` if not, keep it otherwise people may find they are limited to commands by other bots as they can't vote, etc. And depending on what links you want filtered can easily be customized in the "link_filter" array just below.

```
link_filter = [".com", "http", "https:", ".gg", "discord."]


@client.listen('on_message')
async def message(message, member: discord.Member = None):

    if message.author.bot:
        return
        
    for word in link_filter:
        if message.content.count(word) > 0:
            await message.channel.purge(limit=1)

            embed = discord.Embed(
                    
            colour = discord.Colour.red())
                
            embed.set_footer(text=f"No links please!")
            embed.add_field(name=f"NO links!", value=(message.author.mention) + ', Your message was deleted because it contained a link.', inline=False)
            await message.channel.send(embed=embed, delete_after=10)
```